# How can I combine multiple functions in one to change images in React

Tags: reactjs

I'm building a section in my react app that will contain 3 cards; each card will contain an image, and below the image will have 2 buttons(more) that will allow the user to change the image displayed by default to another one Onclick event. I already found the solution, but I didn't think that it the best practice.

I created a JSON file that contains some data about each city (as an example), then imported it into each function based on the city name and the ID.
This is an example of what I'd like to create, but using ReactJs: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CnSGozRAiQ

```
  ***// functions to change the images on click for each cards***
const changeCity1 = () => {
     if(scenesData.paris[0].id == 1 && scenesData.paris[0].city == "paris") {
      imageRef1.current.src = scenesData.paris[0].imageURL1;
    }

  }

  const changeCity2 = () => {
    // I'll add city when I use the function for all the images
     if(scenesData.paris[1].id == 2 && scenesData.paris[1].city == "paris") {
      imageRef1.current.src = scenesData.paris[1].imageURL2;
    } 
  }

const changeCity3 = () => {
         if(scenesData.tejMahal[0].id == 1 && scenesData.tejMahal[0].city == "tejMahal") {
          imageRef2.current.src = scenesData.tejMahal[0].imageURL1;
        } 
 }

const changeCity4 = () => {
             if(scenesData.tejMahal[1].id == 2 && scenesData.tejMahal[1].city == "tejMahal") {
              imageRef2.current.src = scenesData.tejMahal[1].imageURL2;
            } 
          }

<div className="item-img">
                  <a className="imago wow">
                    <img ref={imageRef1} alt="image1" />
                    <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="cont">
                <h6>paris</h6>
                <span>
                <div className="text-center">
                      <button className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
                              onClick={changeColor1}>
                            <span className="ls3 text-u">1</span>
                      </button>

                      <button className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
                              onClick={changeColor2}>
                            <span className="ls3 text-u">2</span>
                      </button>
                  </div>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>


<div className="item-img">
                  <a className="imago wow">
                    <img ref={imageRef2} alt="image2" />
                    <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
                  </a>
              </div>
              <div className="cont">
                <h6>Energies of Love</h6>
                <span>
                <div className="text-center">
                      <button className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
                              onClick={changeColor3}>
                            <span className="ls3 text-u">1</span>
                      </button>

                      <button className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
                              onClick={changeColor4}>
                            <span className="ls3 text-u">2</span>
                      </button>
                  </div>
                </span>
              </div>
            </div>
//JSON file
{
            "paris": [
              {     
                "id": 1,
                "city": "paris",
                "imageURL1": "www.example.com"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "city": "paris",
                "imageURL2": "www.example.com"
              }
            ],
        
            "tejMahal": [
              {
                "id": 1,
                "city": "tejMahal",
                "imageURL1": "www.example.com"
              },
              {
                "id": 2,
                "city": "tejMahal",
                "imageURL2": "www.example.com"
              }
            ]
          }
```

Is there any efficient way to do that? By creating one function that can take care of each card.(keep in mind if I want to add more images/buttons).

Comment: i dont understand the structure. what is paris[0] and paris[1] and why do you check if `id === 1`?

Comment: I created a JSON that contains the information for each image that will be displayed. This is an example of what I would like really to achieve, using React Js https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CnSGozRAiQ

Comment: add this json too please

Comment: I think the problem starts from the creation of the json file. how is it created? the structure i guess is wrong

Comment: I created the JSON file to help structure the code as well as minimize it. please check the solution below. Thanks for your efforts anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change the Json key imageUrl and then check the code below hope so this will help you. for now this is static data you can change onClick event data dynamic.

```
const handleChangeImage = (city, index, id) => {
    if (
      scenesData[city][index].id === id &&
      scenesData[city][index].city == city
    ) {
      imageRef2.current.src = scenesData[city][index].imageURL;
    }
  };
    
    

   <div>
      <div className="item-img">
        <a className="imago wow">
          <img ref={imageRef1} alt="image1" />
          <p></p>
          <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="cont">
        <h6>paris</h6>
        <span>
          <div className="text-center">
            <button
              className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
              onClick={() => handleChangeImage("paris", 0, 1)}>
              <span className="ls3 text-u">1</span>
            </button>

            <button
              className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
              onClick={() => handleChangeImage("paris", 1, 2)}>
              <span className="ls3 text-u">2</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
  

      <div className="item-img">
        <a className="imago wow">
          <img ref={imageRef2} alt="image2" />
          <div className="item-img-overlay"></div>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div className="cont">
        <h6>Energies of Love</h6>
        <span>
          <div className="text-center">
            <button
              className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
              onClick={() => handleChangeImage("tejMahal", 0, 1)}>
              <span className="ls3 text-u">1</span>
            </button>

            <button
              className="nb butn light mt-30 full-width"
              onClick={() => handleChangeImage("tejMahal", 1, 2)}>
              <span className="ls3 text-u">2</span>
            </button>
          </div>
        </span>
      </div>
    </div>
    
    
    
 {
    paris: [
      {
        id: 1,
        city: "paris",
        imageURL: "www.example.com",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        city: "paris",
        imageURL: "www.example.coms",
      },
    ],

    tejMahal: [
      {
        id: 1,
        city: "tejMahal",
        imageURL: "www.example.com",
      },
      {
        id: 2,
        city: "tejMahal",
        imageURL: "www.example.com",
      },
    ],
  };
```